# HTTP WMS GetMap using default SLD instead of provided one

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, getmap

Im trying to give a sld with my wms getMap request.
My issue is that instead of using the provided sld it uses the default one.
Am I missing something obvious? 
Here is the request:

```
http://url.dev/geoserver/workspace/wms
?SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.3.0
&SLD=http://url.dev/sld/test.xml
&REQUEST=GetMap
&FORMAT=image/png
&TRANSPARENT=true
&LAYERS=workspace:layername
&transparent=true
&format=application/openlayers
&viewparams=trace:6
&t=355
&WIDTH=256
&HEIGHT=256
&SRS=EPSG:3857
&BBOX=8140237.764258131,5009377.085697312,8766409.899970295,5635549.221409475
```

with sld body beeing a simple red point :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>default_point</Name>
    <UserStyle>
    <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
      <Title>Default Point</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample style that draws a point</Abstract>
      <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
      <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering points -->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>Red Square</Title>
          <Abstract>A 6 pixel square with a red fill and no stroke</Abstract>
            <PointSymbolizer>
              <Graphic>
                <Mark>
                  <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                  <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
                  </Fill>
                </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Using geoserver 2.8.

Comment: Is http://url.dev/sld/test.xml available to geoserver ? Can you try with  the 'styles' parameters (and not the sld)?

Comment: Yes indeed if i put a empty xml or a none existing file -> Error while getting SLD.  See the log for details. So tomcat/geoserver can read that file. When I use the styles param that works fine.

Comment: I think the name of the layer must match the name in the named style

Comment: Even with the xml named as the layer still not rendering the style ='(

Comment: What if you remove the layers parameter from the request, and put it in the SLD.  Alternatively you could try to call the layer without the workspace: prefix; as the workspace is already in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunatly I tried both your ideas but the problem remains... In the end, I've gone with the rest python API to remove and add the styles. And I just add &STYLES=myNewStyle to the getMap request. Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by naming the `NamedLayer` in the xml the same as the Geoserver layer. So if the layer is called `mylayer`, and it is in the `foo` workspace (eg `foo:mylayer`), I needed my sld file to look like this:

`<NamedLayer>
  <Name>foo:mylayer</Name>
...`

I did not need to use the `style` query-parameter in the `GetMap` request.

It all seems to be a bit redundant to me, and if the same sld file is used as the default styling, it works no matter what name I give it.